# Turn string with operations into int?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a short program to do a task. Unfortunately I keep getting an error. The problem boils down to the following.

If I try to run:

```
line = "1+1"
int(line)
```

I would like it to return

```
2
```

However I get the following error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1+1'
```

From looking online this is due to the fact that Python cannot recognize the fact that I have used a non-number. However without some rework I can't get around this.

I was hoping that there is a straight forward method for solving this. I have tried using float but that has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `eval` function.

```
    eval("1 + 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

line = "1+1"
print(ast.literal_eval(line))
# 2
```